# Making a JS PopUp responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi all I am looking to make a JS popUp responsive to be able to viewed on most screen sizes. At the moment the popup loads in  the middle of the page but does not resize when browser is shortened?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none'>
    <div id="popup">
      <center>
        <h2>Popup Content Here</h2>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"    onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ac-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    z-index: 1001;
}
#popup {
    width: 555px;
    height: 375px;
    background: #222;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 375px;
}
```

JS:

```
function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
            if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
            else document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                PopUp('show');
            }, 5000);
        }
```

**Update:**

[Here's whats happening! the popup box is still not resizing to the page dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPZk1.png)

**Update:**

[Thanks for the help @beerwin the following link shows the popup box now floats up in the corner of the page?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC0HX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to set max-width which would help to fit the popup width to screens that are less than 555px(555px - width of the popup). Not sure about your exact requirement but here is what you can do by assuming you need the popup to be aligned horizontally centered.

```
#popup{
  max-width: 555px;
  height: 375px;
  position:absolute;
   /* your rest of the styles */
}

/* To align horizontally center for screens greater than 555px width */
@media (min-width:555px){
  #popup{
      left:calc(50% - 277px); /* 277px is the half of 555px */
  }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3js5mLpb/

Comment: Have a look at the update on my question it has a picture of whats going on? I want the complete box to to be able to viewed when the screen has been minimised. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Got this working with a bit of a combination with @beerwin code.. Thanks a million

Comment: In this case you can upvote both questions and accept whichever helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

Change width to max-width

```
#popup {
    max-width: 555px;
    height: 375px;
    background: #222;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still not working? It will still sit in the same position and the box will be cut off from view as the page is minimised

Comment: replace this property -  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

Answer (score 0):

You have static width  in your deffinition

```
#popup {
    width: 555px;
..
}
```

use '%' eq.

```
#popup {
    width: 80%;
    ...
}
```

or you can use bootstrap classes like col-md-6, col-md-12 (see definition on bootstrap pages), but remove width: 555px;

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still not working? It will still sit in the same position and the box will be cut off from view as the page is minimised. I have added a picture in the link above to show whats happening.

Comment: Remove margins like   top: 50%; left: 50%; after you can see  whole content you can add some margin like 20px;

Answer (score 0):

Change `width` to `max-width`, `height` to `max-height` and add `height: 90%; width: 90%`. This will make it responsive.

Then update your PopUp function to automatically adjust the position of the popup so it always fit in the screen.

**See a working example below:**

```js
function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
         var popup = document.getElementById('ac-wrapper');   
         if (hideOrshow == 'hide') {
            popup.style.display = "none";
         }
         else {
            popup.removeAttribute('style');
            popup.style.marginLeft = (popup.offsetWidth / 2) * -1 + "px";
            popup.style.marginTop = (popup.offsetHeight / 2) * -1 + "px";
         }
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                PopUp('show');
            }, 1000);
        }
```

```css
#ac-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    z-index: 1001;
}
#popup {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    max-width: 555px;
    max-height: 375px;
    background: #222;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none'>
    <div id="popup">
      <center>
        <h2>Popup Content Here</h2>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"    onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case you can upvote both questions and accept whichever helped you most.